# Regedit return value null

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, regedit

Some one help me. 
why this code dont work properly.
still return null.

[image]

```
RegistryKey hklm = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);

RegistryKey rk = hklm.OpenSubKey(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp\IPAll",RegistryRights.ReadKey);

string valueName = "TcpPort";
```

Comment: *What* returns null, exactly?

Comment: i dont no how this work properly but the key is "TcpPort" and value is 3739

Comment: But return null

Comment: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` should not be part of a *subkey* name. Omit that and you're good (assuming the key really exists).

Comment: i put one screeshot to you see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace:

`hklm.OpenSubKey(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp\IPAll",RegistryRights.ReadKey);`

with

`hklm.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp\IPAll",RegistryRights.ReadKey);`

Comment: If you have a different issue, it's worth starting a new question - that way everyone has a chance to give input on the answer